# Outputting sql and sorting into groups at the same time

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having some trouble, What I'm trying to do I pull a set of columns of my database and then place them into tables. but if there are two entries in the database instead of creating a second table for that customer I'm trying to get the data to go into the first table.

```
SELECT
    scs_customer.customer_name AS customer,
    scs_item.item_name AS item,
    scs_order.item_ammount AS quantity,
    scs_order.order_status AS status,
    scs_order.placed_by AS owner,
    scs_order.date_placed

FROM
    scs_order

JOIN
    scs_item
    ON scs_order.item_id = scs_item.item_id

JOIN
    scs_customer
    ON scs_order.customer_id = scs_customer.customer_id

ORDER BY
    scs_customer.customer_name ASC
```

All I can give you is the database query, as I can only do a basic foreach loop.
but when I do a foreach loop at creates multiple tables, but I would like them to to have all of the one customer backorders in one table and another customers bacorders in a separate table.

Answer (score 0):

You can output the table outside of the loop and every time you get to a new customer, close one table and open a new one.

```
echo '<table>';

$lastCustomer = null;

foreach ($orders as $order) {

    // Every time you get to a new customer, start a new table
    if ($lastCustomer != $order['customer']) {
        echo '</table><table>'
    }

    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$order['customer'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$order['item'].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';

    // Update the "last customer" so next loop around we can compare
    $lastCustomer = $order['customer'];

}

echo '</table>';
```